# Get result from procedure with specific database

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have this procedure:

```sql
ALTER procedure dbo.scUsuarioCorrecto
    @usrLogin nvarchar(15),
    @usrPassword nvarchar(255)
AS
    select case when exists 
        (select * from Usuario where usrLogin = 
            @usrLogin and usrPassword = @usrPassword
            AND usrHabilitado = 1) 
        then CAST(1 as bit) else CAST(0 as bit) end as correcto;
```

I cannot change it, so i gotta work around it, how do i capture that bit from C#, i already connected to the database and i been able to call some procedures, but i'm having problems with this one

tried to set a parameter as output with this:

```
SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("correcto", SqlDbType.Int)
{
   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
cmd.Parameters.Add(result);
```

but i get the "to many parameters" error, sorry if i'm making a silly error, i literally started with C# today, i used the search button too.

Comment: You really have to start with a [tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/), not by typing randomly into the code editor.

Comment: you're effectively lying to your code as to how that parameter works. When you create a SqlParameter it is meant to be a representation of what live in the database. The database is not using this as an output parameter, therefore your code can't make that happen.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you are executing your stored procedure and trying to read it as if there was an [Output parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If you cannot modify your stored procedure to provide an output parameter, then modify your code to something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Your Connection String";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "scUsuarioCorrecto";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrLogin", "Your login");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrPassword", "Your password");

        connection.Open();
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            using (var ds = new DataSet())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    var correcto = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["correcto"];
                } else
                {
                    // Something went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a SqlDataReader would be preferable... but its been a bit since I played w/ ADO stuff

Comment: @misterManager - Actually, you are correct. My Data Adapter is probably overkill and I should modify it to use a DataReader instead. However, because he will only be retrieving one row with one value, it probably wouldn't hurt performance either way.

Comment: still a good answer. DataReader is just a tad more concise using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()){ var correcto = reader["correcto";]} if i'm not horribly mistaken.... give or take a loop or [0] somewhere

Comment: thanks, im getting an error : "System.Data.DataTableCollection does not contain Rows" on here: "ds.Tables.Rows.Count > 0)" am i missing importing something?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to put this in my comment to Icemanind's post (but posted separately for readability). This version uses ExecuteScalar :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Your Connection String";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "scUsuarioCorrecto";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrLogin", "Your login");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrPassword", "Your password");

        connection.Open();
        object obj = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (obj is bool)
        {
            bool correcto = (bool)obj;                
        }
        else
        {
           // either empty result set, or value in row is NULL.
        }  
    }
}
```

General note about ExecuteScalar :

If the SQL request results in an empty result set, then obj will be null (i.e. C# null). If the result set has at least one row, but the value of the first column is NULL (i.e. SQL Server NULL), then obj will be DBNull.Value.

Comment: Your version is definitely more lightweight. My DataAdapter solution was definitely more bloat then needed. I realized it later, but I had company over and couldn't get back on my computer to rewrite it lol.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure only takes the two parameters. In this case, since it's doing a select, you should be able to read from it just like you would from a standard `SELECT` statement.

[Here's a link to get you started.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you need to set the parameter with the OUTPUT

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD
@SalesPerson nvarchar(50),
@SalesYTD money OUTPUT
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @SalesYTD = SalesYTD
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    JOIN HumanResources.vEmployee AS e ON e.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
    WHERE LastName = @SalesPerson;
RETURN
GO
```

Comment: OP says they can't change the procedure and has to work around what they have.